# Header not centered vertically on safari

Tags: html, css

On chrome my website works like it should, but opening the same site on safari, the first header is not vertically centered.
Any suggestions to why that is?

I know a way to overcome this, is to use padding top, but I prefer another solution.

```css
/*body*/
html, body {
 font-size: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 200;
}

/*nav*/
.navbar {
 background: #fff;
 border-bottom: solid #6ed3cf 2px;
 margin: 0;

 /*Kun on scroll!!!
 -moz-box-shadow:    0 2px 0 0 #6ed3cf;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #6ed3cf;
    box-shadow:         0 2px 0 0 #6ed3cf;
    */
}


.navbar p {
 color: black;
 font-weight: 500;
}

.container-fluid {
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
 color: black;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li {
 border-bottom: solid transparent 2px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
 color: #6ed3cf;
}

/*
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:active {
 color: #6ed3cf;
}
*/

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
 background: black;
 -webkit-transition: width .8s, height .8s, -webkit-transform .8s; /* Safari */
    transition: width .8s, height .8s, transform .8s;
}



.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
 border: none;
 background: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
 background: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:visited {
 background: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
 width: 22px;
 transition: all 0.2s;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .top-bar {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: 10% 10%;
}

 .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .middle-bar {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .bottom-bar {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: 10% 90%;
  }

  .navbar-toggle.collapsed .top-bar {
   transform: rotate(0);
  }

   .navbar-toggle.collapsed .middle-bar {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .navbar-toggle.collapsed .bottom-bar {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }

  #topper {
   outline: none;
  }

/*Header*/
.header {
 /*/Users/jonashansen/Desktop/hjemmeside/img*/
 background: url(/img/arg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 position: relative;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(60, 195, 191, 0.7);
 min-height: 100%;
 display:flex;
   justify-content:space-between;
   align-items: center;
}

#rowheader h1 {
 font-weight: 200;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 3em;
}

#rowheader h2 {
 font-weight: 200;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 2em;
}
/*
#rowheader h1 {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-size: 3em;


}
*/

/*Section1*/
#section1 {
 text-align: center; 
 margin-top: 3em;
 margin-bottom: -4em; 
 height: auto;
 position: relative;
}

.anchor {
 display: block;
 height: 3em;
 visibility: hidden; 
}

#section1 h2 {
 font-size: 2em;
 font-weight: 200;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0 2.5em 0.5em;
 display: block;
}

#section1 h3 {
 font-weight: 200;
}

#section1 p {
 line-height: 2em;
 padding: 1em 0 0;
}

#section1 a {
 color: #3DD0AC;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#section1 a:hover {
 color: black;
}

/*Section2*/
#section2 {
 line-height: 1.8em;
 height: auto;
 margin-top: 2em;
 margin-bottom: 2em;
 position: relative;
}

#section2 h2 {
 font-size: 2em;
 font-weight: 200;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0 2.5em 0.5em;
 display: block;
}

#section2 h3 {
 font-weight: 200;
}

#section2 p {
 padding: 0 0 0.5em;
 padding-bottom: 2em; 
}

#section2 a {
 color: #3DD0AC;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#section2 img {
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#img-wrapper {
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#img-wrapper img {
 -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}

#img-wrapper img:hover {
 -webkit-transform:scale(1.1); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.1); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.1); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.1); /* Opera */
    transform:scale(1.1);
}

/*Section3*/
#section3 {
 height: 50%;
 background: #6ed3cf;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0 0 0.5em;
 height: 20em;
}

#section3 h2 {
 font-size: 2em;
 font-weight: 200;
}

#section3 i {
 padding: 0.5em;
 color: black;
}

/*Footer*/
#footer {
 background:#fff;
 color: black;
 height: 6%;
 width: 100%;
 display: table;
}

#footer a {
 font-size: 0.8em;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: top;
   display: none;
   padding-top: 1.2em;
   color: black;
   font-weight: 500;
   text-decoration: none;
}

#footer p {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: table-cell;
  padding-bottom: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Jonas Suonpera Hansen - Web developer</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>             
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="img/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/@media.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" id="topper" href="#"><p>&lt;&frasl;BY&#95;SUONPERA&gt;</p></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#About">About</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#My_Work">My Work</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!-- Header -->
 <div class="header">
  <div class="container" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
   <div id="rowheader">
    <h1>JONAS SUONPERA</h1>
    <h2>Web Developer</h2>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<!-- Section1 -->
 <div id="section1" class="container">
 <span class="anchor" id="About"></span>
  <h2>About</h2>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h3>Me</h3>
    <p>blablablablablablablablablabalbalbal</p>
    <p>Check out my <a href="#">Linkedin</a>, or <a href="/docs/Resume.pdf" download="Resume">download my resume</a> if you want to know more.</p><br><br> 
   </div>
  </div>   
 </div>



<!-- Section2 -->
 <div  id="section2" class="container">
 <span class="anchor" id="My_Work"></span>
  <h2>My Work</h2>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div id="img-wrapper">
     <a href="#"><img src="/img/photographer.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <h3>Photographer's Portfolio</h3>
    <p>blablablablabla<a href="#">Go check it out!</a></p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<!-- Section3 --> <!-- Brug scss til at vertical align text. Se her http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/ -->
 <div id="section3" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
  <div>
  <span class="anchor" id="Contact"></span>
   <h2>Want to get in touch?</h2> 
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <p>blablablabla</p>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> 
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i   ></a>  
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>


<!-- Footer -->
 <div id="footer">
  <a id="topper" href="#topper">BACK TO TOP</a>
  <p>Copyright &copy; 2016 Jonas </p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks exactly the same in both Firefox and Safari here. That is vertically centered.

Comment: Try this: http://bysuonpera.com

Comment: This is far too much code to read. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I guess this could depend on what version of Safari you're using. Also, I see that your header has some sort of clearfix pseudo element on it. Try removing it and see if that does anything (as pseudo elements are affected by flexbox). Also, clearfixes are redundant when using flexbox.

Comment: It looks exactly the same here. Firefox 50.1.0, and Safari 10.0.2 (the webpage, that is, not the example)